# systemctl cannot start. "Sudo systemctl start apasn" I don't understand the error

Tags: sudo, systemd, systemctl

I want to register the service with systemd according to the reference book.
However, if you enter `sudo systemctl start apasn`,

```
#.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon (apasn)
Requires=apasn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=administrator
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/administrator/apasn
ExcecStart=/home/administrator/apasn/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn/apasn.sock person_manager.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You will get an error.
And I can't solve it.

> Failed to start apasn.service: Unit apasn.service is not loaded
>   properly: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status
>   apasn.service' for details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Linux and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

sudo systemd-analyze verify daphnei.service
It was done after changing ExcecStart to ExecStart.